# Wordpress Multisite installation is not behaving as shown in instructions

Tags: wordpress, multisite

I have been following these instructions to get CiviCRM Multisite installed and working.

https://docs.civicrm.org/installation/en/latest/multisite/wordpress/

I am almost at the bottom, where it has specified that we go back to:

```
Now back to WordPress Network Admin, CiviCRM Admin Utilities, "Domain" tab
```

But what is shown on the images is not the same as what I am seeing.

I don't have the "Add New" button next to CiviCRM domains. SO I can't create a new Domain.

The below is a screen grab from the instructions.

[image: This is from the instructions]

=====================

I have to note that the instructions can be ambiguous about what terminology means. It talks about Domains, but its not at all clear if its talking about a website domain, or a domain within CiviCRM.

THere are small clues in the code where it talks about domain_id and domain_group_id.

But I am just inferring that.

There are steps missing out of those instructions that should be in there. Specifically, when adding lines to wp-config.php, and adding entire files (civicrm.domains.php), the instructions MUST mention that you have to replace the URLs and the server paths with paths relevant to your specific server.

In any case, I'd be grateful for any insights.

Thanks